# Loading .obj storing in string using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

My program generates .obj at run-time (stored as string) and now I want to load it using load() function in three.js (OBJLoader).
Inside the load(), it uses HTTP request to retrieve the .obj file which has already existed in the server directory.

Is there any other method that I don't need to generate a new .obj file in server directory and load it again??

If it isn't possible, how can I generate a .obj file in server directory automatically??

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OBJLoader.load` function calls the `parse` function after the loading is complete, You should be able to call this function yourself sending the text that would usually be in an .obj file.

```
var myObj = THREE.OBJLoader.parse(text);
```

The source can be seen [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/OBJLoader.js)

Answer (score 2):

I made it by overriding load function to bypass the url check like this:

```
        var objstring: string = "...." // This is your obj file 
        var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

        // Add a localtext parameter and an if check if url == ""
        loader.load =   function load( url, localtext, onLoad, onProgress, onError ) {
            var scope = this;
            var loader = new THREE.XHRLoader( scope.manager );
            loader.setPath( this.path );
            loader.load( url, function ( text ) {
                if (url==""){
                    text = localtext;
                }
                onLoad( scope.parse( text ) );
            }, onProgress, onError );
        },

        // Now you can use either url or directly string input.
        loader.load( '', objstring, function ( object ) {
            object.traverse( function ( child ) {
                if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
                }
            } );
            scene.add( object );
        });
```